# Bootcamp - is it OK to delete windowssupport.dmg after installing windows?

Tags: bootcamp

As the title says, I've already installed Windows by bootcamp and all works well. Now I've found this windowssupport.dmg in Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support/Bootcamp. Can I just delete it? I'm low on disk space.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

**windowssupport.dmg** is a large but disposable file. System requires it once when you installing Windows. After that you've got no reason to keep it at your drive.

Comment: Thanks. Could you point me to a source that explains it or briefly explain how are you sure that's the case.